# How to control the displayed precision when sending `std::chrono::locale_time` to a c++ stream?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm almost happy with this:

```
const auto time = std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
std::cout << time;
```

It prints:

```
2023-07-26 21:08:47.2889025
```

that's great, but I'd like it to print slightly less decimals, for instance:

```
2023-07-26 21:08:47.289
```

Is there some `iomanip`-like ways of specifying the desired precision?
Something like:

```
std::cout << std::chrono::setprecision(3) << time;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `floor` it to `milliseconds`, either when you call `now`, or when you store it, or when you print it:

```
const auto time = std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
std::cout << std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time);
```

Or use `round` or `ceil` depending on your rounding preference.

Comment: Even better than an  `iomanip`-like solution, thanks!